# How to move notification navigation for different activity when app is background and killed state

Tags: android

```
  private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Displaying data in log
    //It is optional

    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    Log.e("ggjhgjh", String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData()));

    String title = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    String Subtitle = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {
        JSONObject jsonObjectItem = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        jsonObjectItem = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
        handleDataMessage(jsonObjectItem, title, Subtitle);
    } else {
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            JSONObject jsonObjectItem = null;
            jsonObjectItem = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
            handleDataMessage(jsonObjectItem, title, Subtitle);

        }
    }

    //Calling method to generate notification
    //sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

public void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json, String title, String subTitle) {
    Intent intent = null;
    Bundle bundle;
    String requestId, packetType, packetDetails, totalpacket, donarImage, pTime, pAddress;

    try {
        if (title.equals("New Coupons in store")) {
            String couponName = json.getString("name");
            String couponId = json.getString("coupon_id");
            String categoryId = json.getString("category_id");
            String couponPoint = json.getString("coupon_point");
            String couponImage = json.getString("image");
            String couponStatus = json.getString("status");
            String noOfcoupon = json.getString("no_of_coupon");
            String usedcoupon = json.getString("used_coupon");
            String storeId = json.getString("store_id");
            String merchant_id = json.getString("merchant_id");
            String description = json.getString("description");
            String couponstartDate = json.getString("start_date");
            String couponEndDate = json.getString("end_date");
            CouponModel couponModel = new CouponModel(couponName, couponId, categoryId, couponPoint, couponImage, couponStatus, noOfcoupon, usedcoupon, storeId, merchant_id, description, couponstartDate, couponEndDate);
            intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, Activity_CouponDetails.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("couponModel", couponModel);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
        } else if (title.equals("Your Request is Accepted")) {
            requestId = json.getString("id");
            packetType = json.getString("packet_type");
            packetDetails = json.getString("packet_detail");
            totalpacket = json.getString("total_packets");
            donarImage = json.getString("donar_image");
            pTime = json.getString("food_cook_time");
            pAddress = json.getString("address");

            intent = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, Activity_RequestDetails.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            bundle = new Bundle();
            intent.putExtra("pickupId", requestId);
            intent.putExtra("packetType", packetType);
            intent.putExtra("packetDetail", packetDetails);
            intent.putExtra("totalPackets", totalpacket);
            intent.putExtra("donar_image", donarImage);
            intent.putExtra("time", pTime);
            intent.putExtra("address", pAddress);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);

        }
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            //PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(subTitle)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setColor(0xff493C7C)
                    .setLights(0xff493C7C, 1000, 1000)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, myNotification);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove notification payload completely from your server request. Send only Data and handle it in onMessageReceived() otherwise your onMessageReceived will not be triggered when app is in background or killed.

I had the same problem. It is easier to use the 'data message' instead of the 'notification'. The data message always load the class onMessageReceived.

In that class you can make your own notification with the notificationbuilder in onMessageReceived.

```
 @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
        }

        private void sendNotification(String messageTitle,String messageBody) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0 /* request code */, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500};

            Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                    .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(pattern)
                    .setLights(Color.BLUE,1,1)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

write like this in your notification service class and make sure service is defined in your manifest file

```
    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

          String title = data.getString("title");
          String message = data.getString("body");

          Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
            Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);



        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);
            resultIntent.putExtra("frag","Notification");

//                // check for image attachment
//                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, "", resultIntent);
//                } else {
                    // image is present, show notification with image
//                    showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), "Matrix", message, new Date().getTime(), resultIntent, imageUrl);
//                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getStackTrace());
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getCause());
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


  /**
 * Showing notification with text only
 */
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);
}
```

This is Notification util class to check app is background or not and other things of modification of notification.

```
  public class NotificationUtils {
    private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle;
    private static int value = 0;
    private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 237;

    public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
        showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
        value++;
    }

    public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
        // Check for empty push message
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
            return;


        // notification icon
        final int icon = R.drawable.ic_status_notification;

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        mContext,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                );

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                mContext);
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
         inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.profile);
               mBuilder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);

        final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
//
//        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
//
//            if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {
//


                if (bitmap != null) {
                    showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
//                } else {
//                    showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
//                }
//            }
//        } else {
//            showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            playNotificationSound();
        }
    }


    private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

//        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_status_notification)
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Matrix Messages");
        inboxStyle.addLine("You have "+value+" new  notification");
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
        bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
        bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
        Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_status_notification)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify("Matrix",Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
     * the notification tray
     */
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Playing notification sound
    public void playNotificationSound() {
        try {
            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method checks if the app is in background or not
     */
    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            try {

                List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
                ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
                if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                    isInBackground = false;
                }
            }catch (SecurityException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }

    // Clears notification tray messages
    public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    public static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
            return date.getTime();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```